# Using HP-UFT, is Is there anyway to tell whether or not an object in the object repository is being used in other tests?

Tags: hp-uft

I'm currently using UFT -- I have a GUI test, and there's a web element object in one of my tests I'd like to delete/update, but I'm worried it's being referenced by another test in our test suite. (I am coming into a test suite that someone else built)

Is there anyway to tell whether or not an object in the object repository is being used in other tests? (Without having to go into each individual test and action to find out?)

Answer (score 1):

My way would be simple recursive file search.

1. Open EditPlus
2. Search -> Find In Files
3. Find What = 
   File Type = *.mts | *.vbs | *.qfl
   Folder =
4. Select the Include Sub Folder Check Box
5. Click Find

Answer (score 1):

You can use Search>View>Find (or ctrl+F) from UFT and select to look in entire solution

Answer (score 0):

Open "Script.mts" file from every action and search for your object name. If you find the object, write the script name and line number where your object exists, in a file.

Use the below code:

```
'strScriptsPath is the path where your test script folders are placed.

Set strScripts = objFSO.GetFolder(strScriptsPath).SubFolders
For Each Script In strScripts
    strAction = strScriptsPath & "\" & Script.Name & "\Action1\Script.mts"
    If objFSO.FileExists(strAction) Then
        'Open Script in NotePad
        Set strFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strAction, 1)
        Do While Not (strFile.AtEndOfStream)
            strLine = strFile.ReadLine
            If InStr(1, strLine, strObjectName) > 0 Then
                iVerificationCount = objSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
                iCurrentRow = iVerificationCount + 1
                objSheet.Cells(iCurrentRow, 1) = Script.Name
                objSheet.Cells(iCurrentRow, 2) = strLine
                If strFile.AtEndOfStream Then
                    objSheet.Cells(iCurrentRow, 3) = strFile.Line
                Else
                    objSheet.Cells(iCurrentRow, 3) = strFile.Line - 1
                End If
            End If
        Loop
        strFile.Close
        Set strFile = Nothing
    End If
Next
Set strScripts = Nothing
```

To be able to use this code, declare objFSO object and write a piece of code to create an excel and get objSheet.

You can also replace the object name using the below code:

Use the For Each Loop as mentioned above

```
strScript = strScriptsPath & "\" & strScriptName & "\Action1\Script.mts"
strFind = "Old Object Name"
strReplace = "New Object Name"
Set strFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strScript, 1)
strData = strFile.ReadAll
strNewData = Replace(strData, strFind, strReplace)
strFile.Close
Set strFile = Nothing
Set strFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strScript, 2)
strFile.Write strNewData
strFile.Close
Set strFile = Nothing
```

** You just need to write this entire code in a .vbs file and run that file.